# How to specify filename in os.path.join in python

Tags: python

I have

```
fruits = [ apple, pineapple, oranges, mango, banana ]
size = [small, medium, large]
```

I am trying to create paths for all combinations of fruits with sizes as below:

```
for fruit, size in itertools.product(fruits, sizes):
    main-directory = sys.argv[1]
    sizefilepath = os.path.join(maindirectory, fruit, "business", fruit_size.dot)

    try:
       sizefile = open(sizefilepath, "r")
    except:
       print("could not open" +sizefilepath)
    sizefile.close()

     estimatefilepath = os.path.join(maindirectory, "get", "estimate", "of", fruit_size.txt)  
     try: 
        estimatefile = open(estimatefilepath)
     except:
        print("could not open"+estimatefilepath)
     estimatefilepath.close()
```

When I execute the code it gives an error that fruit_size is not defined. and when I define

```
fruit_size = [different comibinations like apple_small etc.]
```

it gives an error that there is no attribute as .txt for string.

How to tackle the error? 
Also My remaining code makes use of sizefile and estimatefile. How can I sequence the execution? 
like for all fruit I want to execute it one by one.
Currently if I try, I get value error : I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: This cannot be your actual code, since the indentation is wrong and `main-directory` cannot be the name of a variable (hyphens are not permitted).

Comment: oh. bymistake I wrote there. it is my code only. it should have been maindirectory. while writing code in post, I missed the indentation.

Comment: Do you want the files to be called as <fruit>_<size>.txt ?

Comment: yes the files in directory are named as apple_small.dot , apple_medium.dot, apple_small.txt and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sizefile filename you want is something like - `<fruit>_<size>.dot` , example - `apple_small.dot` and the second file name needs to be `<fruit>_<size>.txt` then what you are using is wrong, python will assume `fruit_size` to be an object with `.dot` to be a variable inside that object , which is not the case, you want to use string concatenation here.

Example -

```
for fruit, size in itertools.product(fruits, sizes):
    maindirectory = sys.argv[1]
    sizefilepath = os.path.join(maindirectory, fruit, "business", fruit + "_" + size + ".dot")

    try:
       sizefile = open(sizefilepath, "r")
    except:
       print("could not open" +sizefilepath)
    sizefile.close()

     estimatefilepath = os.path.join(main-directory, "get", "estimate", "of", fruit + "_" + size + ".txt")  
     try: 
        estimatefile = open(estimatefilepath)
     except:
        print("could not open"+estimatefilepath)
     estimatefilepath.close()
```